# use dynamic rs() to get column from query

Tags: sql, dynamic, asp-classic

I have created a dynamic query that will return 5 columns with dynamic column names. It will always return the last 5 years as column name.

For example, this year it will retrun these colum names:

```
2014    2013    2012    2011    2010
```

But next year it will be:

```
2015    2014    2013    2012    2011
```

At the moment I use this code to get my values:

```
get_2014 = rs("2014")
get_2013 = rs("2013")
get_2012 = rs("2012")
get_2011 = rs("2011")
get_2010 = rs("2010")
```

This will work for this year, but not for next year. So I thought I could work with an array and something like this:

```
ShowLastXyears = 5
thisYear = Year(now)
dim get_years()
redim get_years(ShowLastXyears)
sql = ...
rs.open sql ...
do until rs.eof
    For k = 0 to ShowLastXyears-1
        get_years(k) = rs(thisYear-(k))
    Next
    rs.movenext
loop
rs.close
```

But then I get this error:

```
Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
```

at line "get_years(k) = rs(thisYear-(k))"

Also tried

```
...
get_years(k) = rs(""""thisYear-(k)"""")
...
```

As result:

```
Expected ')'
get_years(k) = rs(""""thisYear-(k)"""")
----------------------^
```

What is the correct way to do what I want?

**Update:**

Found that I can work with this code:

```
get_years(0) = rs(0)
get_years(1) = rs(1)
get_years(2) = rs(2)
get_years(3) = rs(3)
get_years(4) = rs(4)
```

Is this the only solution, or is it also possible with dynamic rs(...) name?

Comment: Rather then updating your question consider posting an answer that way you can accept it gain reputation and also lay the question to rest. Otherwise it will hang around unanswered like a bad smell. If you have concerns about answering your own question and accepting it, don't it's encouraged by SO. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Lankymart I didn't want to propose it as answer because I thought there would be a much better solution. Tnx for the hint!

Comment: That's fine but still doesn't stop you putting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question would be to replace the `get_years(k) = rs(""""thisYear-(k)"""")` with this:

```vbs
get_years(k) = rs(CStr(thisYear-k))
```

If you're getting the old `Item cannot be found...` then the reason will most likely be that the field doesn't exist.  Try outputting the field names generated by your script on the page first then compare them with your dynamic query.

Comment: That will work but so would `get_years(k) = rs("""" & thisYear-(k) & """")` just missing the string concatenation (`&`) which is what the error points to.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that would, as the process would append the quotation marks to the beginning and end `"2014"` not `2014`. It's very unlikely that the process defined the field names with the quotation marks.

Comment: Yep your right meant `get_years(k) = rs(thisYear-(k) & "")`, `CStr()` is cleaner though. +1

Comment: @Lankymart - I've got to admit that I do append empty speech marks as a cheat ... yep! I'm a bad person!  ;o)